# Design pattern to best implement batch api requests that happen transparently to the calling layer

Tags: kotlin, batch-processing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a batch processor that I want to refactor to be expressed a 1-to-1 fashion based on input to increase readability, and for further optimization later on. The issue is that there is a service that should be called in batches to reduce HTTP overhead, so mixing the 1-to-1 code with the batch code is a bit tricky, and we may not want to call the service with every input. Results can be sent out eagerly one-by-one, but order must be maintained, so something like a flow doesn't seem to work.

So, ideally the batch processor would look something like this:

```kotlin
class Processor<A, B> {
    val service: Service<A, B>
    val scope: CoroutineScope
    fun processBatch(input: List<A>) {
        input.map {
            Pair(it, scope.async { service.call(it) })
        }.map {
            (a, b) ->
            runBlocking { b.await().let { /** handle result, do something with a if result is null, etc **/ } }
        }
    }
}
```

The desire is to perform all of the service logic in such a way that it is executing in the background, automatically splitting the inputs for the service into batches, executing them asynchronously, and somehow mapping the result of the batch call into the suspended call.

Here is a hacky implementation:

```kotlin
class Service<A, B> {
    val inputContainer: MutableList<A>
    val outputs: MutableList<B>
    val runCalled = AtomicBoolean(false)
    val batchSize: Int

    suspended fun call(input: A): B? {
        // some prefiltering logic that returns a null early
        val index = inputContainer.size
        inputContainer.add(a) // add to overall list for later batching
        return suspend {
            run()
            outputs[index]
        }
    }

   fun run() {
        val batchOutputs = mutableListOf<Deferred<List<B?>>>()
        if (!runCalled.getAndSet(true)) {
            inputs.chunked(batchSize).forEach {
                batchOutputs.add(scope.async { batchCall(it) })
            }
            runBlocking {
                batchOutputs.map {
                    val res = result.await()
                    outputs.addAll(res)
                }
            }
        } 

    }

    suspended fun batchCall(input: List<A>): List<B?> {
        // batch API call, etc
    }
}
```

Something like this could work but there are several concerns:

1. All API calls go out at once. Ideally this would be batching and executing in the background while other inputs are being scheduled, but this is not .
2. Processing of the service result for the first input cannot resume until all results have been returned. Ideally we could process the result if the service call has returned, while other results continue to be performed in the background.
3. Containers of intermediate results seem hacky and prone to bugs. Cleanup logic is also needed, which introduces more hacky bits into the rest of the code

I can think of several optimizations to the address 1 and 2, but I imagine concerns related to 3 would be worse. This seems like a fairly common call pattern and I would expect there to be a library or much simpler design pattern to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to find anything. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by using `Deferred`. The solution I would use is:

1. When the caller makes a request, create a `CompletableDeferred`
2. Using a channel, pass this `CompletableDeferred` to the service for later completion
3. Have the caller suspend until the service completes the `CompletableDeferred`

It might look something like this:

```kotlin
val requestChannel = Channel<Pair<Request, CompletableDeferred<Result>>()

suspend fun doRequest(request: Request): Result {
    val result = CompletableDeferred<Result>()
    requestChannel.send(Pair(request, result))
    return result.await()
}

fun run() = scope.launch {
    while(isActive) {
        val (requests, deferreds) = getBatch(batchSize).unzip()
        val results = batchCall(requests)
        (results zip deferreds).forEach { (result, deferred) ->
            deferred.complete(result)
        }
    }
}

suspend fun getBatch(batchSize: Int) = buildList {
    repeat(batchSize) {
        add(requestChannel.receive())
    }
}
```